# CSOM UnauthorizedException only in IE

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I have quite a common CSOM provider hosted app. (On Premise, HighTrust) Inside this app I use the infamous

```
using (var clientContext=GetContext()) {

   ...   
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

(I can provide more code if needed, but as this works in most browsers this should not be a code issue)

On the dev machine, everything works fine (any browser).
At the customer, Chrome works and Firefox works. But the Internet Explorer (9 and 11) throw a 401 error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuildersb)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryImplementation(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud...

Could it have anything to do with enforced proxy settings for IE (GPOs)? Another option to check out if your farm is configured to use NTLM and depending on your architecture and how you create the ClientContext:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2010/05/08/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works/